# Column 'u_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  `attendence`.`u_id` ,
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y') as  `date`,
        `attendence`.`checkin`, 
        `attendence`.`checkout`,
         `users`.`firstname`,
         `users` .`lastname`
 FROM  `attendence`
 INNER JOIN  `users` ON  `attendence`.`u_id` = `users`.`u_id`
 WHERE  DATE_FORMAT( DATE,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '$combined' AND `u_id`='$u_id';
```

please help guys

when i removed AND `u_id`='#u_id it works but returns all employee details'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
`u_id`='$u_id';
```

by

```
`users`.`u_id`='$u_id';
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify what table should the column `u_id` came from since both tables has this column.

```
AND `attendence`.`u_id`='$u_id';
```

OR

```
AND `users`.`u_id`='$u_id';
```

choose one that satifies your needs. Anyway, either of the two functions the same since they are the linking columns of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `u_id` in multiple tables that you are using in your query then you need to specify which `u_id` you want to use.

use this in your where clause:

```
`attendence`.`u_id` = '$u_id';
```